# Maintaining position of visitor with js/html?

Tags: jquery, html, size, anchor

I've noticed on a quite few sites, that you have the main content in the center, and on each side there is a bar with php links. And when you click on the links, it will not get me to the top of the page again, but it will remember my position on the site. I wonder how to do that, I heard you can do that with jquery easily, but I have no idea how. With HTML as far as I know you can only make an anchor internally, but not externally to other pages. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you saying the links pull in data from another site?

Comment: I'm creating a webpage with everytime the same header, footer, etc which also contains the links on the site. But if I open a link, a php file is loaded and ONLY changes the content. So I only pull another <div id='content'>.

Comment: Well you can use a simple .load() function in jquery to load blocks of html into a target container. http://api.jquery.com/load/ I am not entirely sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, browsers 'remember' your last position in pages. to check it you can browse to a website, scroll to a specific point in the page and then hit 'refresh'.

after the page reloads the browser should scroll you back to where you left.

BUT, if you wish to write some mechanism yourself with javascript, you can always create some sort of dictionary with a page url as key, and number of pixels scrolled from top as value, and store it within client-side (cookie, localStorage, etc.) as long as you use it internally in your site.

i don't think it's possible to preserve user locations on foreign sites.

hope that helps.

Comment: The thing  is I only change the content with these links, so only the div with id='content' has other lines of codes

Comment: to be honest, i'm not sure what exactly you need- can you please try to provide an example or something to what you have now, and what you wish to have?

Comment: It's very simple and sorry for the bad explaining; I'm creating a game written in php(mysql)/html and a little bit of javascript. Once logged in you are linked to index.php. index.php has a included header, and within that header is the head/style/title/the navigation(sidebars), the start of the content div, and the footer. When I click on a link(a php file) in the side bar, it will have the same header/footer etc, only a different content. I want to remain at the same position I am, as I was on when I clicked the link, so not going back to the top agian.

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/dVPQw/ You can also use the load function to load a portion of html (so a container with an id for example)

Answer (score 0):

You create something like a click function along these lines:

```
 $('#nav a').click(function() {
   return false
 });
```

return false will stop the page reloading and then you can bind a load function to the click event.

If you post some code (or use jsfiddle) I or someone else will be able to give you a bit more adivce.

Check the load function on jquery: http://api.jquery.com/load/

I think it does exactly what you need.